# Is RPM able to control the files in home folder without confirmation?

Tags: rpm, malware

RPM extension file can be run by double clicking no matter what's inside the package, and then it asks for the root password in order to install something to your system, but if I don't give it, will it cause any harm to my files in home folder?

I'm sure I downloaded the RPM from the correct URL but I'm worried about the Man-In-The-Middle attack, the 10MB file is far away from the size it should be 100MB as the offcial website described, so maybe download session was stopped by the Internet connection failed, or maybe it is the size of malware?

Answer (score 3):

In principle any program you run by double clicking **can** harm the files in your home folder (assuming you have write permissions there, which is the normal case).

The program that is invoked by clicking the RPM is less likely to be malware as it came with the distribution installation, but the scripts and executables in the RPM can contain malware and those do have access to your home-directory (or more correctly to any files the user account with which the RPM is clicked is opened).

Your question if **will** cause any harm cannot be answered, as that depends on several things including the package contents. It might though, so you should use RPMs from trusted sources.

(If the RPM contains malware, then giving the root password would allow it to do even more damage).

Answer (score 2):

If you'e suspicious of any RPM related files you should always download them first and inspect them prior to installing them.

#### Example

```
$ rpm -qpl /home/saml/rtmpdump-2.4-0.1.20110811gitc58cfb3e.fc14.x86_64.rpm
/usr/bin/rtmpdump
/usr/sbin/rtmpgw
/usr/sbin/rtmpsrv
/usr/sbin/rtmpsuck
/usr/share/doc/rtmpdump-2.4
/usr/share/doc/rtmpdump-2.4/COPYING
/usr/share/doc/rtmpdump-2.4/README
/usr/share/man/man1/rtmpdump.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/rtmpgw.8.gz
```

These files can be extracted to a temporary directory for further inspection:

```
$ rpm2cpio /home/saml/rtmpdump-2.4-0.1.20110811gitc58cfb3e.fc14.x86_64.rpm | \
  cpio -idmv
./usr/bin/rtmpdump
./usr/sbin/rtmpgw
./usr/sbin/rtmpsrv
./usr/sbin/rtmpsuck
./usr/share/doc/rtmpdump-2.4
./usr/share/doc/rtmpdump-2.4/COPYING
./usr/share/doc/rtmpdump-2.4/README
./usr/share/man/man1/rtmpdump.1.gz
./usr/share/man/man8/rtmpgw.8.gz
296 blocks
```

We can then inspect the contents further.

#### Checking signatures

You can confirm that the RPM is signed using a GPG key that you already have. If so then it's likely that the RPM is perfectly fine and can be trusted.

```
$ rpm -K /home/saml/rtmpdump-2.4-0.1.20110811gitc58cfb3e.fc14.x86_64.rpm
/home/saml/rtmpdump-2.4-0.1.20110811gitc58cfb3e.fc14.x86_64.rpm: sha1 md5 OK
```

Notice that it says "sha1 md5 OK" at the end. That means that the RPM was signed with a signature and it checks out as OK.

If it fails, it can for a variety of reasons, such as:

1. not signed
2. signature corrupt
3. you're missing its signature key

*For example:*

```
$ rpm -K rpm-2.3-1.i386-bogus.rpm
rpm-2.3-1.i386-bogus.rpm: size PGP MD5 NOT OK
```

Details on using RPM in this fashion are discussed further in the Maxium RPM tutorial, titled: [Maximum RPM: Taking the Red Hat Package Manager to the Limit](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-checksig-using-rpm-k.html).

#### Verifying your system using RPM

For further reading on how to use RPM for checking if your files have been tampered with take a peek at this article on SANS titled: [Intrusion Detection FAQ: Verifying Files with Red Hat's RPM](http://www.sans.org/security-resources/idfaq/rpm.php).

#### References

- [10.3. Checking a Package's Signature](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-check-rpm-sig.html)
- [HowTo: Extract an RPM Package Files Without Installing It](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-extract-an-rpm-package-without-installing-it.html)

Comment: Checking what files are extracted isn't enough. You also need to check the scripts that run on installation.

Comment: @Gilles - true! You want to investigate the contents of the RPM for any type of nefariousness.

Comment: Run `rpm -qp --scripts some-strange.rpm` to check scripts. (IMO scripts are the most important part as they *certainly will* run immediately on installation as opposed to actual files that *may* run depending on their location and your further actions.)

Answer (score 0):

In short - if you **don't** give your password when asked for by the RPM install software - the content of the RPM file will not be parsed and **can not** harm your system in any way.

If you do give your password (and you are an administrator or you gave the root password), then the RPM can be used to install malicious software on your system, run it with administrator permissions and access any file on your system.

Always make sure you download software from the software manufacturer and verify RPM signatures. Fortunately, the built-in software manager in your Linux operating system will do this for you automatically, so allways try first to see if the software manager has what you need before you go and download files from the big bad internet.